# Im making a save/load and my load is not working. what did i do wrong?

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
echo off

goto Save/Load

:Load 
cls
echo Type in the name of your Load
set /f ld="Enter:
< %ld%.sav
(
  set /p highscore=
  set /p User2=

> `Blockquote`

  set /p points=
)

pause
Goto Save/Load
:exit
exit
```

Comment: Perfectly straight-forward question, once it was reformatted. Why was it put on hold 90 minutes after it was edited to make sense?

Answer (score 1):

When reading from a file and using parenthesis, the parenthesis need to start on the same line as the `< file`.

```
< %ld%.sav
(
  set /p highscore=
  set /p User2=
  set /p points=
)
```

needs to be

```
< %ld%.sav (
  set /p highscore=
  set /p User2=
  set /p points=
)
```

Comment: What do you mean it crashed? Where does it fail?

Comment: Turn echo on and run the script from a command line (so the Window doesn't just close), to check what line it fails at.

Comment: when I run the load that's when it closes out. *crashes at the load

Comment: I understand. I'm going to go ahead and assume that you are not calling the `load` batch file from a command prompt, and that you are instead just double clicking the file in your file explorer to run it. Something is causing your script to error and end, therefore the screen will close before your script has finished. To find out where that is happening, open up a command prompt and run the file from there, with echo turned on.